# Reparameterising likelihood

Tags: bayesian, prior

In the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453160/why-does-log-p-mu-log-sigma-y-textconstant-n-log-sigma-frac12-s) it is mentioned that, when calculating the log posterior of a Normal distribution with a uniform prior on $(\mu, \log\sigma)$, we can write down the same likelihood form for the parameterisation $p(y \mid \mu , \sigma)$ as we would for $p(y \mid \mu , \log\sigma)$.

I'm a little confused by this i.e. why the likelihood doesn't change for the parameterisation $p(y \mid \mu , \log\sigma)$?

Any help or further explanation appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by *doesn't change*.

Let's start with rewriting the likelihood from parameters $\mu,\sigma$ to parameters $\mu, \sigma^2$

The likelihood in terms of $\sigma$ is
$$L(\mu,\sigma; y) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

The likelihood in terms of $\sigma^2$ is
$$L(\mu,\sigma^2; y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

The only difference is that I've written $\sigma$ as $\sqrt{\sigma^2}$ in the  denominator of the second one. They are the same expressions, and you normally wouldn't think twice about either of these being correct.

Why can I do this? Because $\sigma$ isn't random  in the context of the likelihood. It's just a number, 17 or something.

The need for transformation comes when you have distribution (a measure) on $y$ or $\sigma$, and you need to transform the density to take account of the transformation  of the measure.  If $y$ is measured in feet, a probability density  in $y$ has units feet$^{-1}$; if you transform to $z=y^2$, you have $z$ in square feet and the probability  density needs to  be transformed to be in feet$^{-2}$.

If you do what you were probably told not to do in calculus and write
$$f(y;\mu,\sigma^2)\,dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\,dy$$
you can (not entirely legitimately but clearly) say there are issues with transforming  $y$ because you need to fix up $dy$, but not with transforming $\sigma$ or with replacing $2\pi$ with the [equivalent mathematical constant](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/let-s-use-tau-it-s-easier-than-pi) $\tau$

The same thing happens with $\log \sigma$.